# Can addEventListener to an audio tag for play, but not set an onplay function

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, html5-audio

This does not work:

```
document.getElementById("audio").onplay = function () {
   alert("in");
};
```

Also tried to use "onPlay", same result.

However, this does work:

```
document.getElementById("audio").addEventListener("play", function () {
   alert("in");
}, false);
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: So, have you found any solution? Same problem here...

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to switch between the "play and pause" states take a look here 
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/

It should fire the first time you play when using onplay but it won't fire after that 
therefore you should create a button that toggles both states

```
var playpause = document.getElementById('playpause');
video.onpause = function(e) {
  playpause.value = 'Play';
  playpause.onclick = function(e) { video.play(); }
}
video.onplay = function(e) {
  playpause.value = 'Pause';
  playpause.onclick = function(e) { video.pause(); }
}
```